# Is it possible, 2 spread have 1 sheet to use farpoint spread

Tags: spread, farpoint

For example, 'A' spread and 'B' spread have same spread sheet(same design, and same formulars). So, if change the value in 'A' spread than change the same value in 'B' spread automatically. It is sure the same cell. Is it possible to simply?

Please, understand my english. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `CellChanged` event.

```
fpSpread1.Sheets[SHEET_A].CellChanged += new FarPoint.Win.Spread.SheetViewEventHandler(sheetA_CellChanged);

void sheetA_CellChanged(object sender, FarPoint.Win.Spread.SheetViewEventArgs e)
{
   fpSpread1.Sheets[SHEET_B].Cells[e.Row, e.Column].Value = fpSpread1.Sheets[SHEET_A].Cells[e.Row, e.Column].Value;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

simply use this:

fpSpread2.Sheets[1]=fpSpread1.Sheets[1];

hope it woks fine.